# Synthesize only setter to declare mutable class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to create Mutable and Immutable classes.

There are Person protocol, Person class, and MutablePerson class.

I would like to create name property, and synthesize only getter for 
Person class, and setter for MutablePerson class. How can I do this?

```
@protocol Person <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *name;

@end

@interface Person : NSObject <Person>

@end

@interface MutablePerson : Person

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

@end
```

There are errors when I try to synthesize setter in MutablePerson class.
How can I synthesize only setter for property?

Comment: Generally a Mutable Class should provide methods for getter and setter. If you remove setter methods, it becomes immutable. Are you asking for a class which supports only setters but not getters ? Even if you achieve that how will you read values from that object after setting it ?

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/12398127/2869739

Comment: @GoodSp33d No, I want to create mutable class. With setters and getter s, but it is prohibited to synthesize setter twice.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, I'm not sure why you are using a protocol to determine that you name of your Person when you are using inheritance to create your MutablePerson.

I've set up a basic Person and MutablePerson object using only inheritance, and it seems to work fine:

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *name;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name;

@end

@interface MutablePerson : Person

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *name;

@end
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"

@interface Person ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *name;

@end

@implementation Person

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _name = name;
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation MutablePerson

@end
```

Let me know if this isn't the intended behavior you have in mind, and I will edit my response to help you further if I can.

EDIT: Here is the sample code I used to create an example Person and MutablePerson:

```
    Person *testPerson = [[Person alloc] initWithName:@"TestName"];

    MutablePerson *testMutablePerson = [[MutablePerson alloc] init];
    testMutablePerson.name = @"MutableName";
```